# AppFresh-like software for Windows?

Tags: windows, updates

[AppFresh](http://metaquark.de/appfresh/) is a useful program for Mac OS X. It scans for applications on your computer and does an online check if there are available updates.

[image]

Is there similar software for Windows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[File Hippo's Update Checker](http://www.filehippo.com/updatechecker/) performs similarly to AppFresh - you run a small desktop app, then it communicates to the File Hippo servers and displays an updates list. It can show beta program updates, and even the install path on your system for each program. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's several listed [here](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-software-update-monitor.htm), along with comments regarding each particular software.

Comment: KC Softwares' Software Update Monitor (SUMo) was the one I was trying to think of. I tried it a year ago, and wasn't overly impressed with the results.

Comment: I knew I should have provided a more complete answer than just a link. Oh well - next time.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [UpdateStar](http://www.updatestar.com/) -- not quite AppFresh, but pretty good nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

http://ninite.com/ is another alternative, although I haven't tried this myself, it seems to come fairly well recommended.