# Looking for a program that automatically updates all other programs

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AppFresh-like software for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/7808/appfresh-like-software-for-windows)

I am Looking for a program that automatically updates all other programs.

I forget to install my updates or sometimes I don't even bother to do so (I am so lazy). Is there any app out there which automatically updates my other programs and keeps my apps up to date including the drivers ?

Please enlist some that you have personally used.

Note: I am using on Windows 7 - 64 bit

Comment: By the way look here. [Good info here](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/05/29/software-update-checker-comparison/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows there is [win-get](http://windows-get.sourceforge.net/). I have no idea how well it works however. It does seem to have a large [app list](http://windows-get.sourceforge.net/listapps.php) though.

Comment: How do I use it , any idea ?

Comment: If you go to http://windows-get.sourceforge.net/support.php That should explain things