# Why do Java and Flash not use Windows Update?

Tags: windows, java, flash, windows-update

Windows Update should be the central way to update any software on Windows, but it only updates Microsoft stuff.

Java and Flash use independent ways to update. Flash is annoying when it opens a window when there is an update. If many software would update with independent way, it would be a mess.

Comment: On most GNU/Linux distributions this process is done through a package manager which is used to install (almost) all programs so there is no need for independent updaters.

Comment: @AndrejaKo One of the many things I love about Linux.

Comment: Agreed, the handling of software updates is monumentally better in Linux.  It's hard to be spoiled there, and come back to Windows at all.

Comment: And here is a plug for CoApp, a package manager for Windows, http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Garrett-Serack-Open-Source-on-Windows-and-the-CoApp-Project

Comment: Similar/Related: [Make Windows Update update my program(s)?](http://superuser.com/questions/308782/make-windows-update-update-my-programs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"it only updates Microsoft stuff."

You said it yourself, it only updates Microsoft software.  Windows is a closed-source OS, not an "app store".  They're not in the business of updating software from competing vendors.  Especially Oracle (Java) and Adobe (Flash), as their products compete directly with offerings from Microsoft.

Accepting multiple update venues is just something you're going to have to deal with.

Comment: I thought there was an interface that allows third-party software to update through Windows Update.

Comment: Nope, no such beast.  Microsoft Update (which is related to, but distinct from Windows Update) can update and/or offer Microsoft software (e.g. Silverlight, Security Essentials, Windows Live) and updates for other MS products (Visual Studio, SQL Server, Office, etc.).  Windows Update can also offer hardware drivers -- I'm not sure what the requirements are for this other than WHQL certification.  However, for 3rd party software there's no integrated 1st party update system.  Windows 8's App Store will have this, but it's only going to be for Metro Apps, if I've read correctly.

Comment: This is correct.  Microsoft already gave an explanation on the Windows 8 blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/11/14/minimizing-restarts-after-automatic-updating-in-windows-update.aspx.